# Include after ob_start(), nothing happen

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, render

I'm trying to render my views with a function.

But if start `ob_clean()`, all code after doesn't affect something. If i include before `ob_clean()` I see the template.

```
public function render($template, $data = array())
{
    if (!empty($data))
    {
        extract($data);
    }
    $templatePath = TEMPLATE_DIR . $template . '.tpl';
    ob_start();
    if (!is_file($templatePath))
    {
        return 'No template found!';
    }
    include $templatePath;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your problem, but you can just use [ob_get_clean()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) You don't need to call `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` separately.

Comment: oh really? Ok this doesn't answer my problem. But good to know :) Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can think of is make sure you aren't forgetting to echo the result of the `render()` function.

Comment: i need to echo? I made a test.tpl file and in there only a word to test. If i include this normal, without ob_clean() all works.

Comment: You need to use `echo render()`. Alternatively, you could replace `return $content` with `echo $content`

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you very much :D And I'm sitting here and wonder why this stupid things doesnt work. It works now. Thank you

Comment: Since that worked for you, I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `return $content` with `echo $content`.